# Python join tables based on '<=' and '>='

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark-sql

I am working on transferring pyspark code to python. In that process i have landed into a challenge wherein i have the below code in spark sql which i need to change to python

`select b.id as tno, a.* from dfrno a, dft b where a.v = b.v1 and (a.rno >= b.start_rno and a.rno <= b.end_rno)`

Since i am new to python i am not sure how to go about this. And i am eager to understand the methodology since this would be quite interesting. I can use only native python packages. I tried to split this into two steps and complete but the join will effectively do the job only with the >= <= condition. It would be of great help if you can get this resolved. 
Below is pictorial representation of the tables and the output required. Thanks

[image]

Comment: It does not make sense to transform an SQL query to Python. Give us more context!

Comment: Its pyspark-sql to python, nothing conceptual to make sense. The Logic must be same. This transformation is required for my project. To give more context, i have added an image of what i am trying to do. The table dfrno contains all the rnos 1 to 5. But i need the ones between the start and end rno of dft table. if you see the final table, the rno has only till 3 that is between the start and endrno of dft table.

Comment: What do you mean by "only native python packages"?

Comment: Sorry i might not have worded it correctly. I meant Pandas and Numpy.